# Where should I located a config or init file on Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to load a config file into my Xamarin.Forms proyect. This file is a simple `.txt` that has a `JSON` with the config properties. My `C#` reader class is on the same folder of my file (on the Xamarin.Form solution) but it says:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException:'Could not find file "/data/user/0/com.companyname.nucleo/files/.local/share/configure.txt"'
```

I'm not sure if a have to located my `.txt` on the resources folder of the `.Android` or `.IOS` proyect.

This is the structure of my proyect. The `C#` reader class is `Configure.cs`:

[image]

This is my code:

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "configure.txt");
string text = File.ReadAllText(fileName);

Console.WriteLine("Contents of WriteText.txt = {0}", text);
```

Also I tried this,

```
var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(Configure)).Assembly;
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("WorkingWithFiles.configure.txt");
string text = "";
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream)) {
     text = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
System.Console.WriteLine("Contents of WriteText.txt = {0}", text);
```

But in this case it throws this exception:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
```

Comment: Check the property of the file, and make it as [embedded resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows#loading-files-embedded-as-resources)

Comment: Yes, I also tried. I actualizated my post.

Answer (score 0):

To embed a file into a Xamarin project, create or add a file and ensure that Build Action: **EmbeddedResource**.

[image]

`GetManifestResourceStream` is used to access the embedded file using its **Resource ID**.

By default the **resource ID** is the filename ***prefixed with*** the default namespace for the project it is embedded in - in your case the assembly is probably `NoguianaNucleo` and the filename is `configure.txt`, so the resource ID is `NoguianaNucleo.configure.txt`.

With the following code you should be able to read the file:

```cs
var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(LoadResourceText)).Assembly;
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("NoguianaNucleo.configure.txt");
string text = "";
using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader (stream))
{  
    text = reader.ReadToEnd ();
}
```

Comment: When I use, LoadResourceText says it is not found. What could I do?

Comment: @DavidZarzosoMoreno Try to replace `LoadResourceText` with `MainPage` (or whatever your Main page is called) and see if the sovles your problem

Comment: Now it throws `**System.ArgumentNullException:** 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: stream'` Stream is null I don't know why. Any idea?

Comment: @DavidZarzosoMoreno Try this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows#embedding-in-shared-projects --- And this for debugging: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows#debugging-embedded-resources